# Setting external oscillator for atmega328p

Tags: atmega, crystal

I'm trying to use a 8MHz Oscillator on an atmega328p. this a part of the whole schematic :

[image]

to that I've set the Fuse byte as calculated 
[image: enter image description here[2]]

then I've set the calculate values in the project :

[image]

To make sure that the uc ist correctly runnion on 8MHz, since I don't have an oscilloscope, I'm trying to toggle a LED each 1 sec, here is the code I've wrote for that :

```
#define F_CPU 8000000
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
int main(void)
{

DDRD |= (1 << PD5); 
    while(1){
        PORTD |= (1 << PD5);  
        _delay_ms(1000);     
        PORTD &= ~(1 << PD5);
        _delay_ms(1000);     
    }
    return 0;
    }
```

As far as I can see the lED take 8sec to change its status ! when I change the value of `F_CPU`  to 1MHz  the toggle is than correct, which means to me that I'm still running the internal oscillator ?

Any idea what I'm missing here ? 
thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You checked the divided by 8 fuse bit. So the CPU runs at 8mhz/8. Uncheck it.

Comment: The devil is in the details.  I've often wished for a "fuses wizard" in the Atmel Studio software that appears when starting a new project, one that asks some simple questions about the engineer's intentions and suggests a set of fuses that fit the task.  It would be so helpful for those of us less familiar with the platform.